# Does a strong acid's conjugate base act as Brønsted-Lowry base?

Tags: acid-base

Why is the conjugate base of a strong acid not considered a Brønsted-Lowry base? Is it because the base is so weak that it essentially has no ability to accept a proton?

(Quote from my lecture notes: "$\ce{Br-}$ is the conjugate base of a strong acid ($\ce{HBr}$), so it will not act as a Brønsted-Lowry base").

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a Brønsted-Lowry base is a chemical substance which can accept a proton.

But in the case of a strong acid, the acid will lose a proton and form a weak conjugate base. Say there is a strong acid HA.

$$\ce{HA + H2O <=> A- +H3O+}$$

So if we take a certain quantity of HA, most of it will undergo the forward reaction since HA is a strong acid. A- is a weak base and will not want to accept the proton and thus only a small quantity of the conjugate base will do undergo the backward reaction. Hence practically, you could say that the conjugate base of a strong acid is not a Brønsted-Lowry base because of its reluctancy to accept the proton.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of halide ions (setting fluoride aside as its  conjugate acid is weak), they *can* act as *Lewis* bases.  They will not, of course, react with solvated protons in aqueous solution but will form complexes with Lewis-acidic transition metal ions.

Answer (score 1):

**All** compounds with an accessable free lone pair can act as a Brønsted-Lowry base. That explicitly *includes* conjugate bases of strong acids.

The only question (and difference) remains how basic these bases are, i.e. what their $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ is. Since it is directly related to the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ by the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{ion}$ of the solvent ($14$ for water), a strong acid will give a weak conjugate base.

However, no matter how weak the base it just takes a strong enough acid to protonate it. Using superacids, even methane $\ce{CH4}$ — a compound that one really would not accuse of having any free lone pairs — could be protonated to give a carbonium ion which quickly decomposed. Its existence was confirmed by the decomposition products the formation of which required the existence of $\ce{CH5+}$.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the Brønsted-Lowry (BL) acid/base theory is in relation to the idea of conjugate acids and bases.

A conjugate base does not always occur when there is interaction between a Lewis acid and a Lewis base, but a conjugate base always occurs when there is a BL acid-base reaction. This is because BL acids-bases are defined by the exchange of protons (H+ ions).

When a BL acid donates a proton to a BL base, the result is a conjugate base (originally the acid) and a conjugate acid (originally the base). And, you must notice that this reaction is in equilibrium! Thus, the reverse reaction is possible. This means that the conjugate base will act like a BL base.

Now, it may be that the initial BL acid that was used was considered a very strong acid, so the conjugate base will be a very weak BL base. Thus, the equilibrium may be favoring the products (K>>>1). As a result, in a closed system, very little conjugate base will undergo the reverse reaction. Nevertheless, at least some should undergo the reverse reaction and it will then act as a BL base!