# Neutral anions in salts and strong acids are similar - is it a coincidence?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, terminology

Recently I was studying salts and my professor provided a list of anions which are considered neutral in salts (that is, they do not change the $\mathrm{pH}$ of an aqueous solution when added as a salt): $\ce{Cl-}$, $\ce{Br-}$, $\ce{I-}$, $\ce{NO_3^-}$, $\ce{ClO_4^-}$.

Now I'm looking at this and I realized the list seems to be almost identical to a list of strong acids: $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{HBr}$, $\ce{HI}$, $\ce{HNO_3}$, $\ce{HClO_4}$, $\ce{H_2SO_4}$.

Is this a coincidence? If it's not, what's the reason, and why is $\ce{SO_4^2-}$ not on the list of neutral ions?

Comment: The *conjugate acid* of a weak base is a strong acid, and the anions you have mentioned are weak bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though couched in different terms, the first part this question is essentially the same as this other one:

[Does a strong acid's conjugate base act as Brønsted-Lowry base?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67685/does-a-strong-acids-conjugate-base-act-as-br%C3%B8nsted-lowry-base)

**No, this is not a coincidence.**  The [conjugate base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_acid) of a strong acid will *always* be a weak base.  The 'neutral salt anions' of your professor's nomenclature are just weak inorganic Brönsted bases.

---

The reason why $\ce{SO4^2-}$ doesn't appear in this list of 'neutral salt anions' is because **it actually *can* noticeably affect the $\mathbf{pH}$ of a solution when added as a salt.**  $\ce{H2SO4}$ is often treated as though it's a diprotic strong acid, but in reality only the first deprotonation is strongly acidic.  This can be seen by examining its acid dissociation constants; from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid):

> $\mathrm pK_{\mathrm a1} = -3$
>   $\mathrm pK_{\mathrm a2} = 1.99$

This $\mathrm pK_{\mathrm a2}$ is about the same as the first $\mathrm pK_{\mathrm a1}$ of $\ce{H3PO4}$ $($[$2.148$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid)$)$, and is actually somewhat *less* acidic than nitroacetic acid $($[$1.68$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitroacetic_acid)$)$.

So, in some cases sulfate may act more or less as a 'neutral salt anion', when the $\mathrm{pH}$ is sufficiently high that it *will* all stay doubly deprotonated, but in others it can *definitely* influence the solution $\mathrm{pH}$. I've actually used sulfate/bisulfate before as an acidic buffer for various projects at work—works great!